# Troubleshoot javascript "not-working" problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is a very fundamental noob javascript troubleshooting problem, that I can't find the answer from sites like

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_error_handling.htm
- https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-your-browser-to-diagnose-javascript-errors/

So in my .html file at the end, I have a line

```
<script src="/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

If my this javascript file have any syntax error or any issue whatsoever, when loading the .html file, the browser will complain to the console, right?

The situation is that my browser is not complaining anything about this javascript file to the console, however,

- the functions defined in it are not working.
- If I move them into `.html` file, into the following section, then the functions are working again.

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myOptions = [ 'Blue',
    'Orange',
    ];
 </script>
```

Through trial and error, I found the culprit is the following innocent looking code:

```js
$('#populate').click(function () {
  alert("populate!")
  var mySelect = $('#myColor');
  mySelect.empty();
};
```

If I remove this piece of code from `/js/myjs.js`, then all the rest of button handling functions are working, but if I add it back, then none of the button handling functions are working any more. I've tried back and forth several times and can confirm it is the case.

What is going on?

I'm asking because I don't know the very fundamental javascript troubleshooting techniques, as you can see, that this is a populate button, there are remaining code that I've removed from the function.

```js
$.each(myOptions, function(index, value) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(value).html(value)
    );
});
```

This is best I can do for now, as the `.html` file is generated from Go back end code, so I can't really provide the simplest demo code. Hope I can get enough troubleshooting info to fix this and the rest of the problems myself. thx.

Comment: You forget to close the parentheses '()' of .click of ' $('#populate').click( ' please close this        and also ';' is missing in  end of line "alert("populate!")"

Comment: Duh! Thanks! So let me ask this way @ArunK, any tool that can help me identify such problem myself?

Comment: Notepad++ is a lightweight tool , it is good for identifying open and closing brackets syntax error, Other wise you can use Visual Studio Code ,it is an advanced tool, and this can be use on not only in JS but also other languages.

Comment: Should be seeing syntax error(s) thrown in browser dev tools console (F12) also

Comment: 1) I'm using Emacs in Linux, and was hoping there is some dedicated tools can do that. 2) No @charlietfl, that is the reason I'm asking this question as I didn't see any syntax error(s) thrown in browser dev tools console.